# A fragment is viewed under all tabs instead of only the one where it should be viewed

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
package com.beacons.railwayaid.raid;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.customlbs.library.IndoorsFactory;
import com.customlbs.surface.library.IndoorsSurfaceFactory;
import com.customlbs.surface.library.IndoorsSurfaceFragment;

public class Navigation extends Fragment{



@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup     container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_layout, container, false);

    IndoorsFactory.Builder indoorsBuilder = new IndoorsFactory.Builder();
    IndoorsSurfaceFactory.Builder surfaceBuilder = new IndoorsSurfaceFactory.Builder();

    indoorsBuilder.setContext(getContext());

    indoorsBuilder.setApiKey("69af5e85-007a-4df5-8715-d1c2c22e206f");



    indoorsBuilder.setBuildingId((long) 979231679);

    surfaceBuilder.setIndoorsBuilder(indoorsBuilder);

    IndoorsSurfaceFragment indoorsFragment = surfaceBuilder.build();

    FragmentTransaction transaction =   getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, indoorsFragment, "indoors");
    transaction.commit();


    return v;
    }
}
```

I am new at android app development and I can't figure out why the fragment is viewed under all tabs. Previously when it was only textview, the app showed specific text under each tab and the app worked but adding this new code somehow causes a fragment to be viewed under all tabs.

Edit:

Adapter Code:

```
package com.beacons.railwayaid.raid;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.List;



public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

List<Fragment> listFragments;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> listFragments){
    super(fm);
    this.listFragments = listFragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return listFragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listFragments.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your adapter code?

Comment: added the adapter code @Wizard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an Adpater to switch between Fragments.
Also in your Adapter you need to provide switch case to choose appropriate fragments based on selected Tabs.

Have a look at this.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

Because you set that only fragment, you have to use switch case or if condition and take Id of the each tab and set at the perticular tab.

Just like this:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(fragmentManager);

        if (role == 1) {
            adapter.addFragment(new MyDetailsB(), "My Details");
            adapter.addFragment(new Biography(), "Biography");
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
    if (st == 1) {
        adapter.addFragment(new MyDetailsB(), "My Details");
        adapter.addFragment(new Biography(), "Biography");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

private static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    private ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    private void addFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```